# Implementing LINQ-like functionality in Scala

Tags: c#, linq, scala

LINQ-to-SQL works in C# because of the compiler "magic" which allows the same syntax for expression trees and anonymous functions. If `users` is `IQueryable` here `users.Where(u => u.UserId == 1)` then compiler will create an expression tree and eventually pass it to the query generator. How the similar functionality is implemented in Scala where there's no such help from the compiler?

Answer (score 2):

Since Scala 2.10 there *is* [help](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/overview.html) from the compiler.

The closest analog to LINQ-to-SQL would be [SLICK](http://slick.typesafe.com/).

Comment: Well, actually not only from 2.10: long before scala macros there were [scala virtualized and lightweight modular staging](http://skillsmatter.com/podcast/scala/high-level-high-performance-programming-with-scala-virtualized-lms-and-delite)

Answer (score 2):

[Slick](http://slick.typesafe.com/) is the official typesafe tool that does what you need